# A union of n sets with diferent order, how can I prove?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let$k_1,k_2,...,k_n$ be any ordination of the indexes $1,2,...,n$then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{k_i}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$

I tried the double contention  technique with no good results, is there a handy theorem I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{k_i}$. Then for some m, $x\in A_{k_m}$. But $ A_{k_m}$  is one of $A_1, \dots A_n$. So $x$ is in on of $A_1, \dots A_n. $ Hence $x \in\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$. We proved so far: $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{k_i}\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$.

Similarly: $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{k_i}$

Comment: Yes sorry i cna't believe it's that easy, So i just take one $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}a_{k_i}$ then for some $l_m, x\in A_{l_m}$, but this $A_{l_m}$ is in fact one of $A_1,...A_n$, so x\in \bigcup A_{k_i}

Comment: $x\in A_{l_m}$ and $A_{l_m}$ is one of $A_1,...A_n;$ say $A_t$. So x is in the union of $A_t$ and other sets in  $A_1,...A_n.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** two sets are equal if they have precisely the same elements.

Comment: This is a true statement, and perhaps it could even be used in a proof of the statement about rearranging the order of sets in a union.  But absent more of those details it hardly answers the Question.  Perhaps you should consider whether this even rises to the level of a constructive Comment.

Comment: @hardmath Well, if you want me to explain it, I will. You just pick an element from the first union, note that it must be in one of the $A_{k_i}$,   which is one of the $A_i$, so that the element is also in the other, and then do it again the other way around. Not only is this hint used in a proof, it basically is the whole proof. Why are you being so rude to me?

Comment: Nothing personal, Samuel.  To you the connection between what you "hinted" and the proof asked for in the Question is probably clear.  However it will not serve as an Answer without more than the one line you wrote.